# Security of open source templates and javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, html, security

I love open source and i have learned a lot from it. One question i have is how do we know that a open source library has no security issues ? Who and how verifies that information ?

For example let us say i am using xyz.js open source javascript library for web user interface, How do i know it (xyz.js) is not sending or communicating information to some server outside of our intention ?

There is a chance that xyz.js can store every key board stroke on client's localstorage and after user completed all his activities on the website and closes the browser tab/browser xyz.js can fire up a call to unknown server and send all the locallystored information.

Question is how do we know that all the open source code is safe to use ?

Comment: Unless you have the time and experience to analyze the code itself, the short answer is you don't; you have to rely on the hope that the product's contributors are benign and/or there is sufficient community monitoring of whatever enters the codebase, and that shady things done by an Open Source project would be well and widely publicized enough to put it out of business, or sprout up a new project. (This doesn't really feel on topic on Stack Overflow though, which really focuses on specific technical Q&A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's open source, it means you (and everybody else) can have a look at the source and see for yourself an check if nothing fishy is going on. And if you don't do it yourself, you hope somebody else in the community has done it.

As people are able to see for themselves, it is less likely for an open source program to be infected by a keylogger than a closed source one.

But in the end it is a question of trust, and you can never be sure. Only a few of the open source projects get actually scrutinized by certified professionals, so you have to rely on the popularity of the library and of its developpers.

Answer (score 1):

> Question is how do we know that all the open source code is safe to use ?

That's why it is called *open source*: because you can see the source code for yourself and see if there are any such problems that you are concerned about.

> For example let us say i am using xyz.js open source javascript
>   library for web user interface, How do i know it (xyz.js) is not
>   sending or communicating information to some server outside of our
>   intention ?

What makes you think that if you are using a closed source, commercial library it wouldn't be doing that? Absolutely nothing and, contrary to open source projects, you don't even have a way to verify that for yourself.